# Magento 1.9: Create a City dropdown, problem with ajax

Tags: magento-1.9

I have a problem with my code ,I follow [This question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/42662/create-a-city-dropdown-problem-with-ajax) but i still get 404 Not Found

i will put my files and please I need help:
file config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Zeo_Citydropdown>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Zeo_Citydropdown>
  </modules>
</config>
```

File app/code/local/Zeo/Citydropdown/etc/config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Zeo_Citydropdown>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Zeo_Citydropdown>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <helpers>
      <citydropdown>
        <class>Zeo_Citydropdown_IndexController</class>
      </citydropdown>
    </helpers>
  </global>
    <!-- start of routers -->
  <frontend>
    <routers>
        <citydropdown>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>Zeo_Citydropdown</module>
                <frontName>citydropdown</frontName>
            </args>
        </citydropdown>
    </routers>
  </frontend>
</config>
```

File app/code/local/Zeo/controllers/IndexController.php:

```
<?php
class Zeo_Citydropdown_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action{

    public function getCitiesAction($selectedCity = '',$stateId){
        $result=array();
        $result['mycities']=Mage::helper('citydropdown')->getCitiesAsDropdown($selectedCity,$stateId);
        $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result));
    }
}
```

File app/design/frontend/cleo/default/opc/onePage/billing.phtml:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 <?php
  $address         = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getBillingAddress();
  //$defaultCity     = $address->getCity();
 ?>
 Event.observe($('billing:country_id'), 'change', function(event) { 
  var defaultCity  = '';
  if ($('billing:country_id').value == 'PS') {
    var defaultCity  = 'Ramallah';
  }
  if ($('billing:country_id').value == 'AE') {
    var defaultCity  = 'Abu Dhabi';
  }
  var selectCountry  =  $('billing:country_id').value;

  var action   = "/index.php/citydropdown/index/getCities/" + selectCountry + "/" + defaultCity;
  if(selectCountry == "AE"){
   var stateId  =  $('billing:country_id').value;
   var request  =  new Ajax.Request(action,
         { 
          method: 'GET', 
          onSuccess: function (data) {
                /* add this code */
                var myjson=data.responseText.evalJSON(true);

                $('billing:city').replace('<select id="billing:city" name="billing[city]" class="required-entry">' + '<option value=""></option>' + myjson.mycities + '</select>');
            },
          onFailure: '', 
         }
        );

  } else if(selectCountry == "PS"){
   var stateId  =  $('billing:country_id').value;
   var request  =  new Ajax.Request(action,
         { 
          method: 'GET', 
          onSuccess: function (data) {
                /* add this code */
                var myjson=data.responseText.evalJSON(true);

                $('billing:city').replace('<select id="billing:city" name="billing[city]" class="required-entry">' + '<option value=""></option>' + myjson.mycities + '</select>');
            },
          onFailure: '', 
         }
        );

  }
 });
 Event.observe($('billing:country_id'), 'change', function(event) {
  var selectCountry  =  $('billing:country_id').value;;
  var defaultCity  = '<?php echo  $defaultCity ?>';
  if(selectCountry != "US"){
   $('billing:city').replace('<input type="text" class=" input-text required-entry absolute-advice " title="City" value="' + defaultCity + '" id="billing:city" name="billing[city]" autocomplete="off">');
  }
 });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to replace this line:

```
var action   = "/index.php/citydropdown/index/getCities/";
```

with

```
var action   = <?php echo $this->getUrl('citydropdown/index/getCities');
```

and add this line after `onFailure: '',` in request

```
parameters: {state_id: stateId, default_city: defaultCity}
```

Comment: i already did this and change it from what you add to this but it also give the same 404 error

Comment: I update my answer, you forgot to add line of parameter in your Ajax request.

Comment: i add it directly through the url but i also try this and not success and keep given me 404

Comment: are you sure you want same access controller other event throught "citydropdown/index" this URL.

Comment: what u mean ? please explain.

Comment: means your controller implement properly or not?

Comment: all controller code are in my question i need to know what i have to do to make it stop given me 404 ?!that was my question man